# How to add children user to an account?

Tags: dailymotion-api

As Dailymotion API [documentation](https://developer.dailymotion.com/guides/mcn/) states, a user needs to have a specific role called "can-adopt-users" in order to accomplish this. However, I can't find a way to activate this role in a user account by API nor user configuration pages. Is this done manually by Dailymotion staff? I tried adding all possible scopes when requesting a new access_token, but this role is never showed in token's properties.

Another question, this role should be activated on parent's account, children's accounts or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API roles are different than scopes, they can't be activated by users and are only granted by Dailymotion staff. You should contact your content manager or [our support](https://faq.dailymotion.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) for this kind of request.

Unfortunately today this feature is unavailable from the API as it is being totally refactored. We will put an update on this documentation page

> Another question, this role should be activated on parent's account, children's accounts or both?

This role is on the API key level of the parent account